# Plain SQL to Codeigniter syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am facing a little trouble with converting this sql to codeigniter syntax. I can use this plain sql and getting results but I have to use `return $this->db->query($sql, array($param))->result();` which I guess doesn't return an array (Not sure though, but i keep getting a error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...", and I have no idea if that query can be modified to return an array or any other workaround is available.) Anyway, I guess the best thing to do for me is to follow the CI syntax of query and then use a `return $query->result_array();`  to get a result array from the query. I know it may be very basic stuff , but somehow I am not able to figure out how to exactly convert this sql to CI syntax. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Here is the sql below.

```
SELECT dirmast.entryID,dirmast.entryTitle,dirmast.entryShortDesc,dirsec.dirsecRefID 
FROM dirmast,dirsec 
WHERE dirsec.drtext = 'something' 
AND dirsec.dirsecRefID = dirmast.entryID 
GROUP BY dirsec.dirsecRefID
```

Comment: What's one got to do with the other? If you want your results in an array, you do `->result_array()`, if you want it as an object, you do `->result()`. Either way, you can use both Active Records and `query()`.

Comment: Wow, Now I feel like an idiot. That solved it, thanks a lot.

Comment: If it did, then I'll post it as an answer and you should accept it. That way others coming to this question will know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your results in an array, you do `->result_array()`, if you want it as an object, you do `->result()`. Either way, you can use both Active Records and `query()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do what you want:

```
$this->db->select('dirmast.entryID,dirmast.entryTitle,dirmast.entryShortDesc,dirsec.dirsecRefID');
$this->db->from('dirmast');
$this->db->join('dirsec','dirsec.dirsecRefID = dirmast.entryID');
$this->db->where('dirsec.drtext','something');
$this->db->group_by('dirsec.dirsecRefID');
```